# Help following proof about the closure of a set in a metric space

Tags: general-topology

I'm self-studying topology from John B. Conway's "Introduction to point-set topology".

Working in the ambient metric space $(X,d)$,
the proposition in question is

> Proposition 1.1.13b: 
> Let $A \subseteq X$. Then $x \in cl A$ implies that for every $r>0$, $B(x;r) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$

The proof he gives is as follows

1. Suppose $x \in cl A$, and let $r>0$
2. Then $B(x;r)$ is open and therefore $X\backslash B(x;r)$ is closed.
3. It cannot be that $A \subseteq X\backslash B(x;r)$ since, by definition, this implies $cl A   \subseteq X\backslash B(x;r)$, contradicting the fact that $x \in cl A$.
4. Thus $B(x;r) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$

**Question 1**: Help me understand the statement in step 3:

$A \subseteq X\backslash B(x;r)$ by definition implies that $cl A \subseteq X\backslash B(x;r)$.

I can't figure out what definition he's referring to, or why the implication follows.

Note that the book so far hasn't mentioned accumuThereforelation points. It gives the following definitions:

1. $int\  a$ is the union of all open sets contained in $A$.
2. $cl A$ is the intersection of all closed sets enclosing $A$.
3. $\partial A = cl (A) \cap cl (X\backslash A)$

**Question 2**: Is this proof correct?

1. Suppose $x \in cl A$, and let $r>0$.
2. Then $B(x;r)$ is open and therefore $X\backslash B(x;r)$ is closed.
3. If $x \in A$ we're done.
4. Otherwise,$x \in ((cl A) \backslash A)$, and so $x$ is on the boundary of $A$, thus also the boundary of $(X/A)$.
5. If $x \in \partial (X\backslash A)$ then $x$ is not an internal point of X\A. Therefore, (by 1.1.13a, an earlier result in the book), for every $r>0$, $B(x;r)$ is not contained in X\A, thus it intersects X\(X\A)=A. QED.

Comment: How did the book define the $\operatorname{cl} A?$

Comment: What does “partial” mean here?

Comment: I included the definition in the OP. partial is  a typo, fixed. $\partial A$ means the boundary of set A.

Comment: Still holding out for comments on Question 2....

Comment: 4 is more clear if you put it: if $x \notin A$ then $x \in X\setminus A$ so $x \in \operatorname{cl}(X \setminus A)$ and as $ x\in\operatorname{cl}(A)$ too, $x \in \partial A = \partial(X\setminus A)$. Then it's correct. But going via 5 and the boundary of the complement and needing an extra result is ugly and too indirect IMO. It does not provide insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that $X\setminus B(x;r)$ is a closed set. By definition:

> $\text{cl}(A)$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$.

If $A\subseteq X\setminus B(x;r)$ then $X\setminus B(x;r)$ is **one** closed set containing $A$. By definition of $\text{cl}(A)$ we obtain$$\text{cl}{A}\subseteq X\setminus B(x;r).$$

Comment: I can see why the definition of cl implies that $cl A$  and X\B *intersect* (namely, for all x in A), but not why $cl A$ is *contained* in X\B. If cl A is the intersection of various sets, one of which is X\B, I don't see why cl A must be a subset of X\B. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: We always have $A\cap B \subseteq A$ for any sets $A$ and $B$. In particular $ \text{cl}(A) =  \text{cl}{A}\cap X\setminus B(x;r) \subseteq X\setminus B(x;r)$

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Would you mind looking at my alternative proof before I accept (at which point no one will point out an error if I made one)?

Comment: I do not have the time now. I suggest that you edit in that you are still looking for comments on your proof, to encourage answers. Best of luck!